# Accumulative Runnable in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, runnable, swingworker, swingx

As part of learning SwingWorker I was going thru the source code where I noticed something called AccumulativeRunnable. From the comment of the AccumulativeRunnable class definition I understand when it is to be used, but when I check the example code few questions came in my mind.

Below is the comment and example code in AccumulativeRunnable abstract class.

> An abstract class (AccumulativeRunnable) to be used in the cases where we need  to perform  some actions on an appendable set of data.
>   The set of data might be appended after the is   sent
>   for the execution. Usually such Runnables are sent to   the
>   EDT.
>
> **Usage example:**    Say we want to implement JLabel.setText(String text)
>   which sends  string to the JLabel.setTextImpl(String text) on the EDT.
>   In the event JLabel.setText is called rapidly many times off the EDT 
>   we will get many updates on the EDT but only the last one is
>   important.  (Every next updates overrides the previous one.)  We might
>   want to implement this in a way that only  the last update is
>   delivered.

```
  AccumulativeRunnable<String> doSetTextImpl =
  new  AccumulativeRunnable<String>()} {

      protected void run(List<String> args)} {
          //set to the last string being passed
          setTextImpl(args.get(args.size() - 1));
      }
  }

  void setText(String text) {
      //add text and send for the execution if needed.
      doSetTextImpl.add(text);
  }
```

## Questions

1. The abstract class AccumulativeRunnable  `implements` `Runnable`.
   That means AccumulativeRunnable class should implement the run
   method right?. But I could see just `protected abstract void
   run(List<T> args);`. How this could be an implementation of the
   `Runnable` interface.
2. Why the `add()` method of AccumulativeRunnable class is
   `synchronized` ?. Can someone explain this with an easy example or
   with the example I provided above.
3. When the `arguments` inside the `add()` method of
   AccumulativeRunnable class will be `null` ? Can someone explain this with an easy example or
   with the example I provided above.
4. How the `add()` method receives an array (T... args) ?.  Can someone
   explain this with an easy example or with the example I provided
   above.
5. In the above example when we call `doSetTextImpl.add(text);` it
   calls the `add()` method of AccumulativeRunnable class. But how this
   internally calling the `run()` method?. I mean who is calling our
   implemented `run()` method internally.

## Entire code in AccumulativeRunnable:

```
public abstract class AccumulativeRunnable<T> implements Runnable {
    private List<T> arguments = null;

    /**
     * Equivalent to {@code Runnable.run} method with the
     * accumulated arguments to process.
     *
     * @param args accumulated argumets to process.
     */
    protected abstract void run(List<T> args);

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>
     * This implementation calls {@code run(List<T> args)} mehtod
     * with the list of accumulated arguments.
     */
    public final void run() {
        run(flush());
    }

    /**
     * appends arguments and sends this {@code Runnable} for the
     * execution if needed.
     * <p>
     * This implementation uses {@see #submit} to send this
     * {@code Runnable} for execution.
     * @param args the arguments to accumulate
     */
    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs") // Copying args is safe
    public final synchronized void add(T... args) {
        boolean isSubmitted = true;
        if (arguments == null) {
            isSubmitted = false;
            arguments = new ArrayList<T>();
        }
        Collections.addAll(arguments, args);
        if (!isSubmitted) {
            submit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends this {@code Runnable} for the execution
     *
     * <p>
     * This method is to be executed only from {@code add} method.
     *
     * <p>
     * This implementation uses {@code SwingWorker.invokeLater}.
     */
    protected void submit() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
    }

    /**
     * Returns accumulated arguments and flashes the arguments storage.
     *
     * @return accumulated arguments
     */
    private synchronized List<T> flush() {
        List<T> list = arguments;
        arguments = null;
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer is the following implementation of `Runnable.run()`. From the Compiler's view, `run(List<T>)` has nothing to do with the method declared by the interface, it's simply a different method with the (coincidentally) same name.

   > public final void run() {
   >       run(flush());
   >   }
2. In graphical environments, you have a lot of concurrency, and `synchronized` prevents the method to be called from two threads at the same time, otherwise you would create a so-called race condition, in which the "faster" thread's update to the list is simply lost. In this specific case this race condition could occur if `synchronized` was missing from `add(T...)` and two threads were trying to add the first element to the list at the same time.
3. Before the first element has been added via `add(T)`. `arguments` is the list of all operations that have to be executed. If you create a new `AccumulativeRunnable<T>`, the `arguments` attribute will be `null` (See line 2) until the first element has been added.
4. `T...` is called a "varargs argument". This is basically just syntactical sugar, and allows you to call `add` in any of the following ways (For more information feel free to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)):

   1. `add(firstObject)`. This will internally convert the one object you supplied into an array of type T with only one element (firstObject).
   2. `add(firstObject, secondObject, thirdObject)` and so on, with any number of arguments. All these arguments will be packed into a single array and supplied to the function.
   3. `add(objectArray)` with objectArray being an actual array of type T. In this case, the internal variable `arguments` will simply reference the supplied array.
5. The answer is written in the quote you supplied:

   > Usually such Runnables are sent to the EDT.

   EDT = Event Dispatch Thread, a "hidden" thread somewhere deep inside the Swing framework that deals with all the button clicks etc. Things that *might* trigger the `run()` method are e.g. a call to `frame.paint()` (Or however that method is called, I'm using JFX, so I'm not an expert on Swing), a button click, a mouse movement, etc.